# Why Docker Dashboard and docker stats show different memory usage values?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I wonder why Docker Desktop Dashboard and `docker stats` command show very different memory usage values?
[image]

Notice Memory Usage is the only significant difference, all others are pretty close.

Comment: Hi were you able to find the answer?

Comment: Hi. Sadly no, I wasn't.